# .Net How to find SuppressMessageAttribute category for a given warning (BC42015)

Tags: vb.net, attributes, warnings

I'm looking for a way how to find a SuppressMessageAttribute catagory for a given warning (BC42015).

After recieving the following warning I would like to suppress it.

```
'SomeLib.SomeInterface.DrawRuler' is already implemented by the base class 'SomeLib.SomeClass'. Re-implementation of function assumed.  C:\Project\somefile.vb  5   115 ALibName
```

Using the SuppressMessage attribute should work but how can I find the relevant Catagory. The following won't work.

```
<CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("IDUNNO","BC42015")>
```

All MSDN examples are pretty useless.
[In Source Suppression Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx)

Rule Category - The category in which the rule is defined. For more information about code analysis rule categories, see some useless link.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're completely right. However it's really annoying that you can't make Visual Studio warnings disappear at will.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general way to discover the category for a **Code Analysis** warning, for use in the `SuppressMessageAttribute` attribute would be to consult the documentation for the warning.

For instance, for [`CA1039`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182154.aspx), we get:

```
TypeName            ListsAreStronglyTyped

CheckId             CA1039

Category            Microsoft.Design

Breaking Change     Breaking
```

Now, for [`BC42015`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwwt4s94.aspx) we don't find such information. Why? Because it's *not* a code analysis warning. It's a **compiler** warning (note that we're in a completely different part of the MSDN library).

So far as I'm aware, there's no local way to override compiler warnings in VB - all you can do is disable the warning at the [project level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y20cc1z.aspx) (but I'll admit, this is hardly ever what you want to do).

Comment: SuppressMessage works just fine with a blank category, surprisingly - so perhaps this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should find a list of warnings on : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380629(v=vs.100).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

P.S: to supress the specific warning, have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/edzzzth4(v=vs.100).aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

In VS2010, you can just right-click the message in the error list and
select "Suppress Message(s)"  You have the option to suppress in source
or in the global project suppression file.

You can look at the generated suppression, see what it did.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer, the code analysis warnings are treated differently from compiler warnings. However, you may use a preprocessor directive (`#Disable Warning` in VB, `#pragma warning` in C#) to suppress this or other compiler warnings at a particular point in your code.

This example shows BC40003 being suppressed where class C2 implements sub1, which has already been implemented by base class C1:

```
    Interface I1
        Sub sub1(arg1 As Integer)
    End Interface

    Class C1
        Implements I1
        Public Sub sub1(arg1 As Integer) Implements I1.sub1
        End Sub
    End Class

    Class C2
        Inherits C1
        Implements I1
#Disable Warning BC40003
        Public Sub sub1(arg1 As Integer) Implements I1.sub1
#Enable Warning BC40003
        End Sub
    End Class
```